# Failed to build uwsgi on CentOS based VPS

Tags: python, centos, pip, uwsgi, vps

I have a problem with install uwsgi on CentOS VPS (hosted by GoDaddy). I compile latest python from source, install pip and virtualenv and when I'm try install uwsgi, I got error:

```
(coderhein)jarvis@server [~]# pip install uwsgi
Collecting uwsgi
  Downloading uwsgi-2.0.11.1.tar.gz (782kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 782kB 506kB/s 
Building wheels for collected packages: uwsgi
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for uwsgi
  Complete output from command /home/jarvis/.envs/coderhein/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-KonabN/uwsgi/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpeGEhfDpip-wheel-:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib
  copying uwsgidecorators.py -> build/lib
  installing to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel
  running install

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for uwsgi
Failed to build uwsgi
Installing collected packages: uwsgi
  Running setup.py install for uwsgi
    Complete output from command /home/jarvis/.envs/coderhein/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-KonabN/uwsgi/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-F6Mjjq-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/jarvis/.envs/coderhein/include/site/python2.7/uwsgi:
    running install

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/home/jarvis/.envs/coderhein/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-KonabN/uwsgi/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-F6Mjjq-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/jarvis/.envs/coderhein/include/site/python2.7/uwsgi" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-KonabN/uwsgi
```

What's wrong with it? I'm not familiar with RHEL-based dists, and don't know, what I need to do. Thanks in advance

UPD. When I'm try to build uwsgi again I got another error:

```
(coderhein)jarvis@server [~]# pip install http://projects.unbit.it/downloads/uwsgi-lts.tar.gz
Collecting http://projects.unbit.it/downloads/uwsgi-lts.tar.gz
  Downloading http://projects.unbit.it/downloads/uwsgi-lts.tar.gz (782kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 782kB 290kB/s 
Building wheels for collected packages: uWSGI
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for uWSGI
  Complete output from command /home/jarvis/.envs/coderhein/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools;__file__='/tmp/pip-Rgghm2-build/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpGH9mvHpip-wheel-:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib
  copying uwsgidecorators.py -> build/lib
  installing to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel
  running install

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for uWSGI
Failed to build uWSGI
Installing collected packages: uWSGI
  Running setup.py install for uWSGI
    Complete output from command /home/jarvis/.envs/coderhein/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-Rgghm2-build/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-oKtSFn-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/jarvis/.envs/coderhein/include/site/python2.7/uWSGI:
    running install
    using profile: buildconf/default.ini
    detected include path: ['/usr/include', '/usr/local/include']
    Patching "bin_name" to properly install_scripts dir
    detected CPU cores: 24
    configured CFLAGS: -O2 -I. -Wall -Werror -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -fno-strict-aliasing -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-format -Wno-format-security -DUWSGI_HAS_IFADDRS -DUWSGI_ZLIB -DUWSGI_LOCK_USE_MUTEX -DUWSGI_EVENT_USE_EPOLL -DUWSGI_EVENT_TIMER_USE_TIMERFD -DUWSGI_EVENT_FILEMONITOR_USE_INOTIFY  -DUWSGI_PCRE -DUWSGI_ROUTING -DUWSGI_VERSION="\"2.0.11.1\"" -DUWSGI_VERSION_BASE="2" -DUWSGI_VERSION_MAJOR="0" -DUWSGI_VERSION_MINOR="11" -DUWSGI_VERSION_REVISION="1" -DUWSGI_VERSION_CUSTOM="\"\"" -DUWSGI_YAML -DUWSGI_SSL -I/usr/include/libxml2 -DUWSGI_XML -DUWSGI_XML_LIBXML2 -DUWSGI_PLUGIN_DIR="\".\"" -DUWSGI_DECLARE_EMBEDDED_PLUGINS="UDEP(python);UDEP(gevent);UDEP(ping);UDEP(cache);UDEP(nagios);UDEP(rrdtool);UDEP(carbon);UDEP(rpc);UDEP(corerouter);UDEP(fastrouter);UDEP(http);UDEP(ugreen);UDEP(signal);UDEP(syslog);UDEP(rsyslog);UDEP(logsocket);UDEP(router_uwsgi);UDEP(router_redirect);UDEP(router_basicauth);UDEP(zergpool);UDEP(redislog);UDEP(mongodblog);UDEP(router_rewrite);UDEP(router_http);UDEP(logfile);UDEP(router_cache);UDEP(rawrouter);UDEP(router_static);UDEP(sslrouter);UDEP(spooler);UDEP(cheaper_busyness);UDEP(symcall);UDEP(transformation_tofile);UDEP(transformation_gzip);UDEP(transformation_chunked);UDEP(transformation_offload);UDEP(router_memcached);UDEP(router_redis);UDEP(router_hash);UDEP(router_expires);UDEP(router_metrics);UDEP(transformation_template);UDEP(stats_pusher_socket);" -DUWSGI_LOAD_EMBEDDED_PLUGINS="ULEP(python);ULEP(gevent);ULEP(ping);ULEP(cache);ULEP(nagios);ULEP(rrdtool);ULEP(carbon);ULEP(rpc);ULEP(corerouter);ULEP(fastrouter);ULEP(http);ULEP(ugreen);ULEP(signal);ULEP(syslog);ULEP(rsyslog);ULEP(logsocket);ULEP(router_uwsgi);ULEP(router_redirect);ULEP(router_basicauth);ULEP(zergpool);ULEP(redislog);ULEP(mongodblog);ULEP(router_rewrite);ULEP(router_http);ULEP(logfile);ULEP(router_cache);ULEP(rawrouter);ULEP(router_static);ULEP(sslrouter);ULEP(spooler);ULEP(cheaper_busyness);ULEP(symcall);ULEP(transformation_tofile);ULEP(transformation_gzip);ULEP(transformation_chunked);ULEP(transformation_offload);ULEP(router_memcached);ULEP(router_redis);ULEP(router_hash);ULEP(router_expires);ULEP(router_metrics);ULEP(transformation_template);ULEP(stats_pusher_socket);"
    *** uWSGI compiling server core ***
    core/utils.o is up to date
    core/protocol.o is up to date
    core/socket.o is up to date
    core/logging.o is up to date
    core/master.o is up to date
    core/master_utils.o is up to date
    core/emperor.o is up to date
    core/notify.o is up to date
    core/mule.o is up to date
    core/subscription.o is up to date
    core/stats.o is up to date
    core/sendfile.o is up to date
    core/async.o is up to date
    core/master_checks.o is up to date
    core/fifo.o is up to date
    core/offload.o is up to date
    core/io.o is up to date
    core/static.o is up to date
    core/websockets.o is up to date
    core/spooler.o is up to date
    core/snmp.o is up to date
    core/exceptions.o is up to date
    core/config.o is up to date
    core/setup_utils.o is up to date
    core/clock.o is up to date
    [thread 1][gcc -pthread] core/init.o
    [thread 2][gcc -pthread] core/buffer.o
    [thread 3][gcc -pthread] core/reader.o
    [thread 4][gcc -pthread] core/writer.o
    [thread 5][gcc -pthread] core/alarm.o
    [thread 6][gcc -pthread] core/cron.o
    [thread 7][gcc -pthread] core/hooks.o
    [thread 8][gcc -pthread] core/plugins.o
    [thread 9][gcc -pthread] core/lock.o
    [thread 10][gcc -pthread] core/cache.o
    [thread 11][gcc -pthread] core/daemons.o
    [thread 12][gcc -pthread] core/errors.o
    [thread 13][gcc -pthread] core/hash.o
    [thread 14][gcc -pthread] core/master_events.o
    [thread 15][gcc -pthread] core/chunked.o
    [thread 16][gcc -pthread] core/queue.o
    [thread 17][gcc -pthread] core/event.o
    [thread 18][gcc -pthread] core/signal.o
    [thread 19][gcc -pthread] core/strings.o
    [thread 20][gcc -pthread] core/progress.o
    [thread 21][gcc -pthread] core/timebomb.o
    [thread 22][gcc -pthread] core/ini.o
    [thread 23][gcc -pthread] co

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/home/jarvis/.envs/coderhein/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-Rgghm2-build/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-oKtSFn-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/jarvis/.envs/coderhein/include/site/python2.7/uWSGI" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-Rgghm2-build
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solve my problem. I'm just download uwsgi source and build from it using:

```
python uwsgiconfig.py --build core
```

UPD. Before building I specified binary name and plugins directory in buldconfig/core.ini